# Pandas: return rows from a dataframe where multiple subsets of columns are non zero

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called **df**

The columns in the dataframe can be logically grouped. Hence I grouped the column names in lists A, B, C where:

```
A = [column_1, column_2, column_3]
B = [column_4, column_5, column_6]
C = [column_7, column_8, column_9]
```

In addition to the columns *column_1* to *column_9*, **df** has one more column called **"filename_ID"**, which is used as the index and thus is not grouped. The olumns *column_1* to *column_9* contain only 0 and 1 values.

Now I want to filter the dataframe such that it only includes rows where there is ***at least one*** non-zero value for each group (A,B,C). As such, I only want to keep rows with the respective filename_ID that fullfill this condition.

I have managed to create a seperate dataframe for each group:

```
df_A = df.loc[(df[A]!=0).any(axis=1)]
df_B = df.loc[(df[B]!=0).any(axis=1)]
df_C = df.loc[(df[C]!=0).any(axis=1)]
```

However, I dont know how to apply all conditions simultaniously - i.e how to create one new dataframe where all rows fullfill the condition that in each logical column-group there is at least one non-zero value.

Comment: `pandas.DataFrame.merge`???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Setup

```
np.random.seed([3, 1415])

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(2, size=(10, 9)),
    columns=[f"col{i + 1}" for i in range(9)]
)

df

   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8  col9
0     0     1     0     1     0     0     1     0     1
1     1     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     0
2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
3     1     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
4     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     1
5     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     1
6     1     0     1     0     0     0     1     1     0
7     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0
8     1     0     1     0     1     0     0     1     1
9     1     0     1     0     0     1     0     1     0
```

---

### Solution

Create a dictionary

```
m = {
    **dict.fromkeys(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], 'A'),
    **dict.fromkeys(['col4', 'col5', 'col6'], 'B'),
    **dict.fromkeys(['col7', 'col8', 'col9'], 'C'),
}
```

Then `groupby` based on `axis=1`

```
df[df.groupby(m, axis=1).any().all(1)]

   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8  col9
0     0     1     0     1     0     0     1     0     1
1     1     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     0
4     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     1
5     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     1
8     1     0     1     0     1     0     0     1     1
9     1     0     1     0     0     1     0     1     0
```

---

Notice the ones that didn't make it

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8  col9
2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
3     1     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
6     1     0     1     0     0     0     1     1     0
7     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0
```

---

You could also have had columns like this:

```
cols = [['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], ['col4', 'col5', 'col6'], ['col7', 'col8', 'col9']]
m = {k: v for v, c in enumerate(cols) for k in c}
```

And performed the same `groupby`

Comment: Wow, this is super helpful! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
column_groups = [A, B, C]
masks = [(df[cols] != 0).any(axis=1) for cols in column_groups]
full_mask = np.logical_and.reduce(masks)
full_df = df[full_mask]
```

Answer (score 1):

Created a csv file with sample data

Sample Input:

```
ID  a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  a6  a7  a8  a9
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
2   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
3   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1
5   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1
6   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0
7   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
8   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1
9   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
10  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
11  1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   1
12  1   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('check.csv')
df['sumA'] = df.a1+df.a2+df.a3
df['sumB'] = df.a4+df.a5+df.a6
df['sumC'] = df.a7+df.a8+df.a9
new_df = df[(df.sumA>1)&(df.sumB>1)&(df.sumC>1)]
new_df = new_df.drop(['sumA','sumB','sumC'],axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    ID  a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  a6  a7  a8  a9
0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
4   5   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1
6   7   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
7   8   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1
10  11  1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   1
11  12  1   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1
```